# Spark update variable incrementally on executors

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

**Situation :**
During a rdd.mapPartitions operation, I need to access some common data (let's call it topology, because it is) that are loaded from databases by the driver.

The executors on each batch can update / insert inside this topology objects and at the end will write directly in database. It is NOT the result of the operation, just some attributes.

After each batch the driver fetch the new data from the database and we start again a new batch.

**Problem :**
In some scenarios, the deserialization time is huge and increase as the elements in the topology increase also.

**What I tried :**
For this reason I implemented a version of our topology with Broadcast, but this solution is useless when a modification happens on all the batches, as it will have to broadcast the entire object each batch instead of only the few modifications.

**Question :**
I'm close to replace Broadcast by a cache and fetch the new data at beginning of the batches on each executor as we can have 40 executors in the same time for one project. I don't really like this solution as it will increase the pressure on the database. I would like to have a Broadcast that I can update incrementally.

Does spark implement such feature ?
Is it possible to do it ourself ?

Comment: How big is your topology data? Could the executor load the topology data so you would avoid this back and forth?

Comment: Can be from 1mb to 2gb at this date. The "increment" in the worst case scenario is about 20% of the topology size. Yeah the executors can do this, it's the "cache" solution I envisaged, but this require a "SELECT * FROM ... WHERE autoinc > ?" from all the executors at the same time.
I would prefer the driver to do this "update" and then push this update to the executors

Comment: Can you talk a little more about the main process? I am curious if you cannot optimize the whole process instead of just this part… what is like to know is what you are doing with this topology data: are you joining it? Filtering it? Are you adding data from other sources? When you say you add data, is it in a relational database or just in memory?

Comment: I want to avoid sending the topology each time when the main process is already super fast. The main process is a "simple" ETL, fully configurable by the user depending of their need. Sometimes we get rdd of 1 partition with a big file in it, sometimes we get thousands of partitions with numerous small file in them. It's for the second case that I need to improve the topology. As the whole partition process is in milliseconds But deserialization of topology is about 5sec.

Comment: The topology is actually a simple copy of some table in memory. Before we were doing a select for each "get" action, but this was really long as you can imagine. So we cache everything. And so are the "update" and "insert" operation. And then they are written on the database at the end of the main process.
Basically, I can't know in advance how the topology will be used. It's only at runtime. Our program is actually interpreting some kind of "no code" configuration.

We write down the topology on a ClickHouse engine. No relation needed.

Comment: If you want to avoid the small files, why do t you repartition your data to avoid the data skewing?

Comment: It has to run in real time. I can't wait to have more files to make the batch bigger.